# Как сделать такой вид агрегации?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, mongoengine

В базе данных хранится документ с примерно следующей структурой:
[image]

Как мне сделать агрегацию, которая в результате вернёт только поле bot, где _id соответствует определенному значению?

Я пытался сделать это через $filter со следующим значением:

`{
    _id: 0,
    bot: {$filter: {
        input: '$clusters.bots',
        as: 'bot',
        cond: {$eq: ['$$bot._id', 'somevalue']}
      }}
    }`

Однако это не работает.